# sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression returns different coefficients every time although random_state is set

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I'm fitting a logistic regression model and am setting the random state to a fixed value.

Every time I do a "fit" I get different coefficients, example:

```
classifier_instance.fit(train_examples_features, train_examples_labels)
LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
          intercept_scaling=1, penalty='l2', random_state=1, tol=0.0001)

>>> classifier_instance.raw_coef_
array([[ 0.071101940040772596  ,  0.05143724979709707323,  0.071101940040772596  , -0.04089477198935181912, -0.0407380696457252528 ,  0.03622160087086594843,  0.01055345545606742319,
         0.01071861708285645406, -0.36248634699444892693, -0.06159019047096317423,  0.02370064668025737009,  0.02370064668025737009, -0.03159781822495803805,  0.11221150783553821006,
         0.02728295348681779309,  0.071101940040772596  ,  0.071101940040772596  ,  0.                    ,  0.10882033432637286396,  0.64630314505709030026,  0.09617956519989406816,
         0.0604133873444507169 ,  0.                    ,  0.04111685986987245051,  0.                    ,  0.                    ,  0.18312324521915510078,  0.071101940040772596  ,
         0.071101940040772596  ,  0.                    , -0.59561802045324663268, -0.61490898457874587635,  1.07812569991461248975,  0.071101940040772596  ]])

classifier_instance.fit(train_examples_features, train_examples_labels)
LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
          intercept_scaling=1, penalty='l2', random_state=1, tol=0.0001)

>>> classifier_instance.raw_coef_
array([[ 0.07110193825129411394,  0.05143724970282205489,  0.07110193825129411394, -0.04089477178162870957, -0.04073806899140903354,  0.03622160048165772028,  0.010553455400928528  ,
         0.01071860364222424096, -0.36248635488413910588, -0.06159021545062405567,  0.02370064608376460866,  0.02370064608376460866, -0.03159783710841745225,  0.11221149816037970237,
         0.02728295411479400578,  0.07110193825129411394,  0.07110193825129411394,  0.                    ,  0.10882033461822394893,  0.64630314701686075729,  0.09617956493834901865,
         0.06041338563697066372,  0.                    ,  0.04111676713793514099,  0.                    ,  0.                    ,  0.18312324401049043243,  0.07110193825129411394,
         0.07110193825129411394,  0.                    , -0.59561803345113684127, -0.61490899867901249731,  1.07812569539027203191,  0.07110193825129411394]])
```

I'm using version 0.14, the docs specify "The underlying C implementation uses a random number generator to select features when fitting the model. It is thus not uncommon, to have slightly different results for the same input data. If that happens, try with a smaller tol parameter."

I thought that setting the random state would make sure there is no randomness but apparently this is not the case. Is this a bug or desired behavior?

Comment: I also noticed that sometimes that this behavior changes between "runs", one time I start python repeated calls to fit generate different coefficients and in other times I restart python I does not. Very strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really desired, but it's a known issue that is very hard to fix. The thing is that `LogisticRegression` models are trained with [Liblinear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIBSVM), which does not allow setting its random seed in a completely robust way. When you explicitly set the `random_state`, a best effort is made to set Liblinear's random seed, but that may fail.

Comment: If it is essential to have exactly the same coefficients, you can write a function `get_logistic_regression_coef` which fits the model and returns the coefficients, and then cache it using `sklearn.externals.joblib.Memory`. That way it will save the results to disk for a given input and reload those at the second call if the input didn't change.

Comment: If in every run all the digits after say 6 decimal places change then for all intents and purposes they are meaningless, no? what about just rounding the coefficients after those say 6 decimal points? that way the results will be deterministic.

Comment: @jonathans There might still be random flukes that cause bigger differences. I feel your suggestion amounts to hiding the problem, rather than solving it (e.g. by installing a different RNG in Liblinear, which is tricky but possible).

Comment: I agree, at this point I'm resorting to what I can personally control and fixing this directly in Liblinear is not one of the things I feel I'm qualified to do.

Comment: Does that also apply for the ‘lbfgs’ and ‘newton-cg’ solvers?

Comment: Does anyone know if there has been a recent fix for this since then? I am using sklearn version 0.19.1

Answer (score 1):

I was baffled by the problem as well, but eventually found that it was also necessary to call `numpy.random.seed()` to set the state of numpy's internal RNG, in addition to passing `random_state`.

This was tested with sklearn 0.13.1.

Comment: This worked for me! Do we know why it works? Perhaps the srand function inside logistic regression uses the global numpy random seed?

Comment: This didn't work for me... I am using sklearn 0.19.1. @P.C. which sklearn version were you using?

Comment: I have both set, but the result is still varying. Do you have to set them to the same value or different values? any tricks there?